# Using make to process files from one arbitrary directory tree into another

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to use *make* to process the contents of an arbitrary directory tree (source) and create another directory tree (target) with the same structure as the source tree.

The subdirectories of the source tree contain files ending in .md (markdown text). The goal is to create a .html file in the target tree for each file in the source tree using pandoc.

The following code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246713/how-to-write-a-make-rule-for-files-of-certain-type-in-a-directory-tree) converts files in the same tree but I don't know how to modify it so it puts the resulting files in another tree.

```
markdown := $(shell find . -name '*.md')

all: $(patsubst %.md, %.pdf, $(markdown))

%.pdf: %.md
    pandoc -o $@ $<
```

I wrote a script that implements the desired functionality using bash but I'd like to do the same using make.

**UPDATE**

In my use case, the directories involved are subdirectories of the
current directory:

- The source directory, ./docs/, contains several (nested) subdirectories
  containing files that end in .md
- The destination directory, ./install/HTML/, does not originally exist but it 
  should be constructed as needed by the make process.

For example, if the file ./docs/info/general/foo.md is modified or added, the make process should create the file ./install/HTML/info/general/foo.html after creating directory ./install/HTML/info/general/ if it does not already exist.

**SOLUTION**

After @MadScientist's post I was able to construct the below solution:

```
SOURCE_DIR := docs
TARGET_DIR := install/HTML

# ----- Get all source file (.md) paths
markdown := $(shell find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name '*.md')

# ----- Strip the source directory and .md suffix
files := $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.md, %, $(markdown))

# ----- Create paths to the target .html files
html  := $(patsubst %, $(TARGET_DIR)/%.html, $(files))

all: $(html)

$(TARGET_DIR)/%.html: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.md
    @echo Converting $< into $@
    dir=`dirname $@`; \
    mkdir --parents $$dir; \
    pandoc -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give too many details, so all I can suggest is this:

```
DESTDIR := newdir

markdown := $(shell find . -name '*.md')

all: $(patsubst %.md, %.pdf, $(markdown))

%.pdf: $(DESTDIR)/%.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<
```